# HTTP : Detect changes in child component when update/save/delete

Tags: http, typescript, angular

I'm learning HTTP as I go. Unsure how to move forward. I'm doing http calls only in my service.

Then I have a class, Teacher, here's some of the methods:

```
export class Teacher {

    public addStudent(value: Student): void {
        this.students.push(value);
    }
}
```

I have a list component that lists teachers, and in that component, the user can click a teacher and move to a detail-page, where it takes user input and adds students to the teacher.

```
export class TeacherDetailComponent implements OnActivate {

    teacher: Teacher;

    constructor(public _service: Service, public _router: Router) {    }

    routerOnActivate(curr: RouteSegment): void {
        let id = curr.getParam('id');
        this._service.getById(id)
            .subscribe(teacher => {
                this.teacher = teacher;
            });
    }

    addStudent() {
        this.teacher.getStudents().push(new Student());
        //what code here?
    }
}
```

There is my headscratcher, how and where do I tell Angular that to update the data for the teacher when a new student is added!

Comment: Could you add the template of your `TeacherDetailComponent` component?

Comment: What does "when the use is done" mean exactly?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes, that is actually part of my question, even though I didn't point that out. I guess it should update the Teacher at every change the user does!?

Comment: @AJT_82 what does "every change" mean?

Comment: When user adds, removes... meaning at every method to be exact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact your question is related to component communication. I would create a shared service for this.

See this doc for more details:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

So I would create a service to notify the list component that a student is added or remove, so it can update the list accordingly. Here is a sample:

```
@Injectable()
export class StudentService {
  userAdded:Subject<Student> = new Subject();
  userDeleted:Subject<Student> = new Subject();

  constructor(private http:Http) {
  }

  addStudent(student:Student) {
    return this.http.post('/users', ...)
        (...)
        .do((addedStudent) => {
          this.userAdded.next(addedStudent);
        });
  }

  deleteStudent(student:Student) {
    return this.http.post('/users', ...)
        (...)
        .do((removedStudent) => {
          this.userRemoved.next(removedStudent);
        });
  }
}
```

So you can update your details component:

```
addStudent() {
  let newStudent = new Student();
  this.studentService.addStudent(newStudent).subscribe(addedStudent => {
    this.teacher.getStudents().push(addedStudent);      
  });
}
```

In the list component:

```
this.studentService.addedStudent.subscribe(addedStudent => {
  // do something
});
```

Comment: I updated my question, since I'm still trying to grasp this... so if you'd look at it, I'd be really thankful!

Comment: There is something to update in the teacher list page when students are updated for a particular teacher?

Comment: No that's why I was kind of wondering why I need to add code there. The code as is, complains `cannot read property isSkipSelf of null`. I'm HORRIBLE at looking at the error codes...

Comment: hmm... I'm looking into EventEmitters, could that possibly help me. Eventemitters are totally new to me, so I'm just looking at how it even works. But could that work, when user makes changes in the detail page, triggers event and 'somehow' tells the Teacher to send http post request to update the data in the db...?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  I updated my question completely at the end... is there no way to do it similarily as I wrote the `addStudent()` at the end? Sorry, I'm bothering you like crazy!

Comment: `EventEmitter`s are for outputs of components, i.e. when you want to implement custom events that can be caught by parent components...

Comment: There are problems like this in the Angular2 github: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8519.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Now I've managed to get an new error :D look at pic in question. any ideas? Thanks!